# SOCKS proxy without ssh command

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

Currently I create a ssh tunnel using: `ssh user@server -D 1234` to use SOCKS proxy. How do I configure server so I can directly connect to socks server?

I want to set firefox socks host to server ip and port, instead of 127.0.0.1 and the port specified with -D parameter.

Comment: The `-D` option of SSH makes the SSH server also act as a SOCKS server -- there is no other SOCKS server in the picture. What SOCKS server are you referring to then?

Answer (score 17):

You'll need to install and configure an actual SOCKS server on the server, such as [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/), [SS5](http://ss5.sourceforge.net/), [Delegate](http://www.delegate.org/) or [Srelay](http://socks-relay.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

You can create a long-running SSH connection on the server to itself using `ssh user@localhost -D 0.0.0.0:1234`.
You can create a script that verify if this command is running and put it on crontab to ensure if the connection fails for some reason it'll restart the job.

Answer (score 2):

You could install something like Srelay, a free Socks proxy server software for Linux: http://socks-relay.sourceforge.net/